# Sort Recyclerview in an ascending order from Parse in android

Tags: android, sorting, arraylist, parse-platform, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to sort integers in an ascending order from Parse, I've never done it before, but this is what I've done in my Recyclerview adapter:

> public class StudentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
private List<LogDetails> detailsList;
private Context context;

public StudentAdapter(List<LogDetails> detailsList, Context context) {
    this.detailsList = detailsList;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public StudentViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.fragment_student, parent, false);

    return new StudentViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final StudentViewHolder holder, int position) {

    LogDetails studentDetails = detailsList.get(position);
    try {
        //For Team A Only
        holder.name_a.setText(studentDetails.getTeam_a().fetchIfNeeded().getString("team_name"));
        String win = String.valueOf(studentDetails.getTeam_a().fetchIfNeeded().getInt("w"));
        String lose = String.valueOf(studentDetails.getTeam_a().fetchIfNeeded().getInt("l"));
        String draw = String.valueOf(studentDetails.getTeam_a().fetchIfNeeded().getInt("d"));
        String play = String.valueOf(studentDetails.getTeam_a().fetchIfNeeded().getInt("p"));
        String points = String.valueOf(studentDetails.getTeam_a().fetchIfNeeded().getInt("pts"));
        holder.w_a.setText(win);
        holder.l_a.setText(lose);
        holder.d_a.setText(draw);
        holder.p_a.setText(play);
        holder.pts_a.setText(points);

        holder.name_b.setText(studentDetails.getTeam_b().fetchIfNeeded().getString("team_name"));
        String win2 = String.valueOf(studentDetails.getTeam_b().fetchIfNeeded().getInt("w"));
        String lose2 = String.valueOf(studentDetails.getTeam_b().fetchIfNeeded().getInt("l"));
        String draw2 = String.valueOf(studentDetails.getTeam_b().fetchIfNeeded().getInt("d"));
        String play2 = String.valueOf(studentDetails.getTeam_b().fetchIfNeeded().getInt("p"));
        String points2 = String.valueOf(studentDetails.getTeam_b().fetchIfNeeded().getInt("pts"));
        holder.w_b.setText(win2);
        holder.l_b.setText(lose2);
        holder.d_b.setText(draw2);
        holder.p_b.setText(play2);
        holder.pts_b.setText(points2);

        holder.name_c.setText(studentDetails.getTeam_c().fetchIfNeeded().getString("team_name"));
        String win3 = String.valueOf(studentDetails.getTeam_c().fetchIfNeeded().getInt("w"));
        String lose3 = String.valueOf(studentDetails.getTeam_c().fetchIfNeeded().getInt("l"));
        String draw3 = String.valueOf(studentDetails.getTeam_c().fetchIfNeeded().getInt("d"));
        String play3 = String.valueOf(studentDetails.getTeam_c().fetchIfNeeded().getInt("p"));
        String points3 = String.valueOf(studentDetails.getTeam_c().fetchIfNeeded().getInt("pts"));
        holder.w_c.setText(win3);
        holder.l_c.setText(lose3);
        holder.d_c.setText(draw3);
        holder.p_c.setText(play3);
        holder.pts_c.setText(points3);

        holder.name_d.setText(studentDetails.getTeam_d().fetchIfNeeded().getString("team_name"));
        String win4 = String.valueOf(studentDetails.getTeam_d().fetchIfNeeded().getInt("w"));
        String lose4 = String.valueOf(studentDetails.getTeam_d().fetchIfNeeded().getInt("l"));
        String draw4 = String.valueOf(studentDetails.getTeam_d().fetchIfNeeded().getInt("d"));
        String play4 = String.valueOf(studentDetails.getTeam_d().fetchIfNeeded().getInt("p"));
        String points4 = String.valueOf(studentDetails.getTeam_d().fetchIfNeeded().getInt("pts"));
        holder.w_d.setText(win4);
        holder.l_d.setText(lose4);
        holder.d_d.setText(draw4);
        holder.p_d.setText(play4);
        holder.pts_d.setText(points4);


    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return detailsList.size();
}

public class StudentViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView name_a, p_a, w_a, l_a, d_a, pts_a;
    TextView name_b, p_b, w_b, l_b, d_b, pts_b;
    TextView name_c, p_c, w_c, l_c, d_c, pts_c;
    TextView name_d, p_d, w_d, l_d, d_d, pts_d;
    View  mView;
    private LogDetails mLogDetails;

    public StudentViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mView = itemView;
        name_a = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.tv_teamA);
        p_a = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.tv_teamA_p);
        w_a = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.tv_teamA_w);
        l_a = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.tv_teamA_l);
        d_a = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.tv_teamA_d);
        pts_a = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.tv_teamA_pts);

        name_b = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.tv_teamB);
        p_b = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.tv_teamB_p);
        w_b = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.tv_teamB_w);
        l_b = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.tv_teamB_l);
        d_b = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.tv_teamB_d);
        pts_b = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.tv_teamB_pts);

        name_c = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.tv_teamC);
        p_c = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.tv_teamC_p);
        w_c = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.tv_teamC_w);
        l_c = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.tv_teamC_l);
        d_c = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.tv_teamC_d);
        pts_c = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.tv_teamC_pts);

        name_d = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.tv_teamD);
        p_d = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.tv_teamD_p);
        w_d = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.tv_teamD_w);
        l_d = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.tv_teamD_l);
        d_d = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.tv_teamD_d);
        pts_d = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.tv_teamD_pts);

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return super.toString() + " '" + "Content View" +
                "'";
    }

}
```

}

I'm having a log table in my recyclerview displaying teams with their points, so the one with most points should come first in an ascending order.

Comment: i am not understand what you can say sort in textview please clarify your quiry in question.

Comment: I just updated it now thanks. "I'm having a log table displaying teams with their points, so the one with most points should come first in an ascending order"

Answer (score 0):

**you can use**

```
Collections.sort(yourlist);
```

Comment: Does it sort according an integer in the row? because I have multiple TextViews in each row but I want it to sort according to a single integer textview .

Comment: In class LogDetails you have implement the method Comparable<LogDetails>, and implement it using Integers; And when you want call Collections.sort(detailsList);